# How to specify a value for a textarea using formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

Trying to give a textarea some default text using the formtastic rails helper. I can't use value like on other inputs, so how can I make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be a limitation or missing feature in Formtastic. For inputs like `:string` you can do `:input_html => { :value => 'whatever' }`, but the "value" of a `textarea` isn't set with a HTML attribute.

Give that a try (we pass the `:input_html` options down to built-in Rails helpers, and maybe they'll do the right thing), otherwise, please submit an issue or a pull request on Github.

Comment: Never thought to try that, I just assumed it wouldn't work because the textarea doesn't work like an input. But yes, worked splendidly. Thankya much, good sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try `:placeholder => placeholder_text`

Comment: Rather not use placeholder, want the default text to be editable. Don't want it to away on focus.

Comment: This doesn't work, anyways. You have to use:
:input_html => { :placeholder => 'Placeholder Text Here' }

Comment: @Mladen Danic, it works without :input_html in Formtastic 2.2.1.